# OpenVPN does not use provided port

Tags: openvpn

I can't use the default 1194 port used by OpenVPN as it is blocked by firewall. I've change the port to 80 on server and started it, everything looks good there.

On the client I've set the port to 80 with following config (IP obfuscated):

```
dev tun
tls-client

remote 1.1.1.1 80
```

Yet when I connect OpenVPN prints out 1194. Where is it taking that from? What's the difference between `link remote` and `link local`?

```
Tue Feb 05 20:26:15 2019 OpenVPN 2.4.6 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Apr 26 2018
Tue Feb 05 20:26:15 2019 Windows version 6.2 (Windows 8 or greater) 64bit
Tue Feb 05 20:26:15 2019 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018, LZO 2.10
Tue Feb 05 20:26:18 2019 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Tue Feb 05 20:26:18 2019 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]1.1.1.1:80
Tue Feb 05 20:26:18 2019 UDP link local (bound): [AF_INET][undef]:1194
Tue Feb 05 20:26:18 2019 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]1.1.1.1:80
Tue Feb 05 20:27:18 2019 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Tue Feb 05 20:27:18 2019 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Tue Feb 05 20:27:18 2019 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
```

Comment: I'll leave this question here for people who really want to run their server on a non-standard port and run into this issue. I managed to get by, using port 1194 on OpenVPN server and then configuring 80 -> 1194 port mapping on my router.

Comment: Your problem was that your server wasn't listening on port 80. If you did have your server listen on port 80 it would have worked.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Well it was. I had changed the server config to port 80. I'm using synology which has a simple GUI for doing this, so you can't really go wrong there.

Answer (score 1):

> OpenVPN prints out 1194. Where is it taking that from?

```
Tue Feb 05 20:26:18 2019 UDP link local (bound): [AF_INET][undef]:1194
Tue Feb 05 20:26:18 2019 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]1.1.1.1:80
```

1194 is the source port on your computer, that the VPN client is connecting out through.  It typically uses that source port, although I'm not sure why it does that - maybe just to make the traffic easy to identify.

80 is the destination port on the server that it is connecting to, which is as you want.

If you add an `lport` directive to your config file, e.g. `lport 4242`, that should allow you to change the source port to something less confusing.